# What data analysis technique should I use for ordinal scale data?

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, t-test, chi-squared-test

I am seeking to confirm that staff members are more likely to perform pro-environmental behaviour if they perceive support from their manager. The behaviours are measured by an ordinal scale (very frequently, frequently, occasionally, rarely and never), and the perception is measured by a likert-scale (strongly agree, agree, neutral disagree and strongly disagree).

What is the appropriate analysis for this? My N is 25 but I can collect more if necessary.

Comment: Do you want a model relating perceived support & environmental behaviors, or do you only need to test if they are related?

Comment: I think test if they are related would be fine. Of course it is better with the model relating but I think it 's too complicated for me.

Comment: what is the scheme for scoring the responses for each of two variables?

Comment: the behaviours scored by very frequently, frequently ... never; and the perceived-support scored base on Strongly agree, Agree ... Strongly disagree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ordinal variables and you want to see if they are associated.  You should just compute an ordinal correlation, such as Spearman's, and test it against a null hypothesis of no association.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so how about the sample size?

Comment: There is nothing necessarily wrong with N=25. The question is simply about how big an effect you want to be able to detect.

Comment: My supervisor did not allow me to use Spearman, she told my sample is too small, if I try to use in my dissertation she will fail me as it against the principle of Spearman test :(. Do you have any reference so I can show her that N=25 is ok/

Comment: @NhatKha, I've never heard of such a thing. I'm not aware of it. My copy of Hollander & Wolfe refers to the large sample approximation for the sampling distribution, but gives no guidance on what N is required to be 'large'. The prove that the mean & variance are correct w/ N=4, but that doesn't mean the shape of the sampling distribution is right, & refers to the case w/o ties, which you would have. You could always simulate the null distribution to be sure.